# Django multiple forms

Tags: django, forms

Let me explain my models first.
If I model SO forum in my models. I would have..

```
Thread
  thread_type (QA or wiki)
  title
  tags
  main_post = models.OneToOneField('Post', null=True, blank=True, related_name='_thread')
  # main_post is question post in QAThread

Post
  thread = models.ForeignKey('Thread', related_name='posts')
  parent_post = models.ForeignKey('Post', blank=True, null=True, related_name='comments')
  raw_html

QAThread(Thread):
  thread = models.OneToOneField(Thread, parent_link=True)
  is_accepted

WikiThread(Thread):
  thread = models.OneToOneField(Thread, parent_link=True)
  converted_to_wiki_at
```

I'm trying to present a form where user can submit data for thread & post.
It seems inline_formset or similar is used for something like this, but it doesn't actually work for me.

(Post has foreign Key to thread, not the sub-class of thread, and I'm creating sub-class of thread instance such as QAThread or WikiThread)

Comment: I think you should use a single form instead of a formset, asking all the information you need, and then building your models with this data.

Comment: How should I process(split) the aggreated request.POST data? If I could do something like `qa_form = QAThreadForm(request.POST); post_form=PostForm(request.POST)` it'll be good enough. ie, Is there an way to pick only the fields that a certain form expects from request.POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the following example code (after some fine tuning) in a function based view for your models:

```
def multiform(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context_dict = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':  # If the form has been submitted...
        # Using a prefix ensures that fields with similar names are not mixed up.
        form1 = ThreadForm(request.POST, prefix="formA")  # A form bound to the POST data
        form2 = PostForm(request.POST, prefix="formB")  # A form bound to the POST data
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            thread = form1.save(commit=False)
            thread.save()
            post = form2.save(commit=False)
            post.thread = thread
            post.save()

    else:
        form1 = ThreadForm(prefix="formA")
        form2 = PostForm(prefix="formB")

    context_dict['form1'] = form1
    context_dict['form2'] = form2

    return render_to_response('template.html', context_dict, context)
```

If you want to use CBVs, things are more complicated.